# PHP zero float returning true

Tags: php, floating-point, boolean

I have a field in my mySQL db table of type decimal (15,4)

I've never experienced this before but if the value is 0.0000 my PHP if statement is returning true!

As a sanity check I even did:

`if(0.0000) echo "Hello World";`

And sure enough, Hello World echo'd out. What the hell is going on? Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Your sanity check works fine for me, PHP v5.2.6

Comment: Yea it was evaluating as expected on my server with PHP 5.3.13 but is evaluating the incorrect way on a different server with the same PHP version. I'm thinking there must be setting in php.ini or something :\

Comment: @Andy, no offense but I don't believe you :) I think you've made an honest mistake in a flurry of debugging attempts.

Comment: @chris embarrassingly enough, you are right :\ suppose that's what I get for working from 9am - 4:30am. Sorry for wasting your time guys!

Answer (score 4):

If it's a float value coming out from DB it will be treated like a string, not like a numeric value. You can try something this:

```
if(floatval($value) > 0) { ... }
```

Where `$value` contains the value from DB.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you got a string `"0.0000"` from db but not `0.0000`.

Try again with:

```
if ((int)$your_value) echo "Hello World";
```

Comment: The sanity check doesn't include a string.

Comment: @KendallFrey He said the value is come from db, so the code in the question is just dummy I think.

Comment: He said he did a sanity check with that statement. I'm quite sure the literal value isn't coming from the DB.

Comment: Kendall is right, It was evaluating as true from the DB so I put the literal value 0.0000 in the statement and got the same result

Comment: @Andy So what is the result of `var_dump((bool)0.000)` in your machine?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this behavior on my PHP version (5.3.3).

I suggest casting the number to *bool* before doing the check: `if ((bool) $float)`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a long time since this question was opened but I thought it might help out someone else.

A float is actual an approximation of the `Real Number`. You will find that not all `Real numbers` can be represented by a float. This might be the reason why you are getting unexpected results. You should have a read of 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php.

If however you need higher precision you should look at using the BC Math lib's http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php.